# Mqtt client program in c

Tags: c, mqtt

I'm using Dev C++ tool. I'm getting an error `undefined reference to 'MQTTClient_create'`.

part of a code of source file(.c)

```
MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please share more details like the definition of `MQTTClient_create` as a start.

Comment: I would like to run this code http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/pubsync.html    And this code use this libs, http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/files.html

Comment: Can you confirm that the libs mentioned in http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/Cclient/files.html are linked to the project.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to include information on what you have already tried when asking a question. Any detail you can supply could be helpful.